# How i can get specific error at guard()->attempt method in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I try make my own authenticate logic in Laravel framework.

In my LoginController i use this login method:

```
    public function login(Request $request) {
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return (ErrorsResponse::haveErrors([ 'common' => 'Слишком много попыток входа' ]));
        }
        $try_validate = $this->validator($request->all())->errors();
        if ($try_validate->messages()) {
            return (ErrorsResponse::haveErrors($try_validate->messages()));
        }

        $auth_data = [
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ];

        if ($this->attemptLogin($auth_data, $request->filled('remember'))) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
            return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                    ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

        // Attemp fail
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        return (ErrorsResponse::haveErrors([ 'common' => 'Ошибка авторизации' ]));
    }
```

But standart `attemptLogin` return only `false` or `true` value, whereas i want receive full info about "why it fail".

Is there a way to get a specific error without writing my own `guard()->attempt`?

Comment: so you want the errors? like "this email is not registered" for example?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yep, something like this.

Comment: The only thing I could come up with so far: it was try find the user by username first, something like this:

$user_try_to_login = User::where('username', $request->username)->first();
if (!$user_try_to_login) {
 return (ErrorsResponse::haveErrors([ 'username' => ['User not found'] ]));
}

Comment: check the method sendFailedLoginResponse that you have from the AuthenticatesUsers trait,with `$this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);`, probably from what it return you can get the errors message

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia no, it just return redirect =(

Comment: try to dd it and see if there is some attribute with the array with the errors

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia return dd($this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request)) also causes only redirect, i don't known why.